# How can I export parameter from excel to games?

Tags: optimization, gams-math

How can I export data from Excel to GAMS? I have a set `i` and parameter `b(i)`.

`b(0)= 30,...,b(10)=18` are:

```
0   30
1   17
2   21
3   32
4   19
5   29
6   24
7   20
8   23
9   27
10  18
```

I have an Excel file with name "Book1", my code results in ERROR 409:

```
Unrecognizable item - skip to find a new statement
looking for a ';' or a key word to get started again
```

Why? What can I do? This is my code:

```
set i/1*10/
parameter b(i)
$call =xls2gms r=sheet2!B3:C13 i=Book1.xlsx o=set.inc
$include set.inc
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add semicolons after each command. The only exception are the $ commands compile time commands. Fx:

```
set i /1*10/;
parameter b(i);
$call =xls2gms r=sheet2!B3:C13 i=Book1.xlsx o=set.inc
$include set.inc
```

Comment: thanks ,I put Semicolon in, but still I have the same error